# Polars - PanicException: Capacity overflow - help needed

Tags: python-polars

##### What language are you using?

Python

##### Have you tried latest version of polars?

Yes.

##### What version of polars are you using?

Polars 0.14.1

##### What operating system are you using polars on?

Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043

##### What language version are you using

python 3.8.8

##### Describe your issue.

Code loops through approx. 3.5k stock price time-series and creates additional columns e.g. moving averages. This works completely fine up to two thirds of the task and then creates the following exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):



 File "file link here", line 219, in <module>
    "Ret": ((df['price']/df['price'].shift(1)-1).ewm_mean(alpha=1-0.97, )*255).round(4),



 File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\polars\internals\series.py", line 3654, in ewm_mean



 File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\polars\internals\frame.py", line 4724, in select



 File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\polars\internals\lazy_frame.py", line 622, in collect



PanicException: capacity overflow




thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'capacity overflow', library\alloc\src\raw_vec.rs:517:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'capacity overflow', library\alloc\src\raw_vec.rs:517:5
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'capacity overflow', library\alloc\src\raw_vec.rs:517:5
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'capacity overflow', library\alloc\src\raw_vec.rs:517:5
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'capacity overflow', library\alloc\src\raw_vec.rs:517:5
```

I do not understand what this error is trying to tell me and have no idea how to debug.

Comment: Could you add the output of Polars `show_versions()` to the question, specifically for the machine that is generating this error?

Comment: More specifically, I'm interested in whether you are using a 32-bit version of Windows.  (I can't tell from the data that you provided.)

Comment: @cbilot, Thanks. I am using 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor. pyarrow is 8.0.0, pandas 1.2.4, numpy is 1.22.1, fsspec 0.9.0, connectorx not installed and xlsx2csv not installed either. Can I provide any other details that might help?

Comment: Potentially related: this issue says that an unsorted time column can cause a capacity overflow error. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5159 Perhaps sorting by time first would fix it?